# UR5 - Robot model does not have a Gripper

Tags: ros, gripper, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If anybody could help, I am new to ROS and we are modeling a Universal Robot 5 from the ROS package supplied however the model does not have the gripper which we have installed in real life. How do I get a gripper on the simulation model?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259547/ur5---robot-model-does-not-have-a-gripper/) by [Biv](https://answers.ros.org/users/30073/biv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How do I get a gripper on the simulation model?

you'll have to create a new xacro macro that combines both the UR5 macro (I'm guessing from `ros-industrial/universal_robot`) and a model of your gripper. Then instantiate that macro and use the resulting urdf as a basis for your further work.

If you haven't already, I'd recommend you do the [Learning URDF Step by Step](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials) tutorials, as that should give you some insight into how this all works.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1